# How do I get Liferay's Javascript PortletURL module to work with friendly URL mappings?

Tags: javascript, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I've set up friendly URL routing for my Liferay portlet, and it's working fine when I generate URLs with the standard JSP tags like so:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="resetUrl">
    <portlet:param name="start" value="5" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

which, given my mapping, produces a lovely URL like:

```
localhost:8080/web/guest/welcome/-/myportlet/5
```

But when I generate URLs using the JavaScript **PortletURL** module, I get the full unfriendly URL. For instance:

```
var filterUrl = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
filterUrl.setPortletId("<%= portletDisplay.getId() %>");
filterUrl.setParameter("start", "5");
location.href = filterUrl;
```

will generate

```
localhost:8080/web/guest/welcome?p_p_id=myportlet_WAR_MyPortletportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&myportlet_WAR_MyPortletportlet_start=5
```

So my question is:
**How can I generate friendly URLs from JavaScript?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do it. You wold have to rewrite the portal_url.js and PortletURLAction.java. 
An other option is to write your own portlet, witch can generate the URL as you need it and access it via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is this approach, a bit tricky -

```
                <portlet:actionURL var="copyNavigationPointURL">
                    <portlet:param name="myaction" value="copy-navigation-point"></portlet:param>
                    <portlet:param name="objectTypeId" value="changeObjType"></portlet:param>
                    <portlet:param name="navigationPointId" value="changeNavPointId"></portlet:param>
                </portlet:actionURL>
```

then write javascript and replace param values like this -

```
function copyNavigationPoint(copyNavigationPointURL) {
    var copyNavId = document.getElementById("navigationPointId").value;
    if (copyNavId==null || copyNavId=='null'){
        alert('error');
        return;
    }
    var objectTypeId = document.getElementById("objectTypeId").value;
    copyNavigationPointURL = copyNavigationPointURL.replace(/changeObjType/i,objectTypeId);
    copyNavigationPointURL = copyNavigationPointURL.replace(/changeNavPointId/i,copyNavigationPointId);

    submitForm(document.hrefFm, copyNavigationPointURL);
}
```

And you have your friendly url.